# PimCore Installation on Windows 10 (Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found))

Tags: pimcore, pimcore-v5

I have install Pimcore in windows 10 and it'll return some errors in browser console and it'll not display any images and css's

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to install pimcore assets using  `php bin/console assets:install` command. Just navigate to system root folder and run the command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install pimcore assets. For pimcore version <6 use `php bin/console assets:install --symlink --relative` but if you are using >= 6 use `php bin/console assets:install web --symlink --relative`